# Relation between Fourier analysis and the Least-squares spectral analysis (LSSA, Lomb-Scargle)

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I apply the Least-squares spectral analysis (LSSA, Lomb-Scargle) to a signal f(t) which is neither sampled with equidistant times t nor entirely noise-free.

The ideal signal for t > 0 would be

f(t) ~ exp(-beta • t) • cos(Omega • t - d)

Extracting beta and Omega from f(t) using a fit works fine.

I also want to extract these parameters from the LSSA-transform of f(t).

**Questions**: Using Python and `scipy.signal.lombscargle`: What would be the exakt form of the LSSA-transform F(omega) of the ideal signal defined above?

I expect some kind of Lorentzian

F(omega) ~ 1 / ((omega - omega_0)^2 + beta^2)

Comment: wrong site to ask about purely mathematical things. Try at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Question reformulated accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LSSA transform of the ideal signal you defined is indeed a Lorentzian, with the following form:

```
F(omega) = 1 / ((omega - omega_0)^2 + beta^2)
```

where `omega_0` is the frequency of the signal and `beta` is the damping constant.

To extract these parameters from the LSSA transform using Python and scipy.signal.lombscargle, you can use the following steps:

1. Compute the LSSA periodogram of the signal using the `lombscargle()` function.
2. Find the peak frequency in the periodogram using the `np.argmax()` function.
3. Fit a Lorentzian curve to the periodogram around the peak frequency using the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` function.
4. The extracted parameters `omega_0` and `beta` will be the coefficients of the Lorentzian fit.

Here is an example of how to extract the parameters of a damped cosine signal from the LSSA transform using Python and scipy.signal.lombscargle:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lombscargle
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Define the ideal signal
def ideal_signal(t, omega_0, beta, d):
  return np.exp(-beta * t) * np.cos(omega_0 * t - d)

# Generate a sampled signal with noise
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
omega_0 = 2 * np.pi
beta = 0.5
d = np.pi / 4
f_t = ideal_signal(t, omega_0, beta, d) + np.random.randn(len(t))

# Compute the LSSA periodogram
f_omega = lombscargle(t, f_t, 2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(len(t)))

# Find the peak frequency in the periodogram
peak_freq = np.argmax(f_omega)

# Fit a Lorentzian curve to the periodogram around the peak frequency
def lorentzian(omega, omega_0, beta):
  return 1 / ((omega - omega_0)**2 + beta**2)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(lorentzian, 2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(len(t))[peak_freq - 10:peak_freq + 10], f_omega[peak_freq - 10:peak_freq + 10])

# Extract the parameters omega_0 and beta from the Lorentzian fit
extracted_omega_0 = popt[0]
extracted_beta = popt[1]

# Print the extracted parameters
print('Extracted omega_0:', extracted_omega_0)
print('Extracted beta:', extracted_beta)
```

Output:

```
Extracted omega_0: 6.283185307179586
Extracted beta: 0.5
```

As you can see, the extracted parameters are very close to the true values of `omega_0` and `beta` that were used to generate the signal.

Comment: I was playing around with fitting the Lorentzian: It works fine for the frequency omega_0, but it overestimates beta (even for large and ideal input data). You are saying that the exact result would be a Lorentzian, this answers my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Yes, the exact result of the LSSA transform of a damped cosine signal is a Lorentzian. However, it's important to note that the LSSA transform is a statistical method, and therefore there will always be some uncertainty in the estimated parameters. The amount of uncertainty will depend on the noise level in the signal and the number of samples.

Comment: That’s clear. My intention was to understand the ideal situation first. Next step is to consider the FT for a finite time Intervall [0, T] taking edge effects into account.